# Problema con acentos al enviar datos $.ajax a pagina ASP

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp

Al enviar mis datos a la página ASP si envío acentos o Ñ me aparecen un montón de caracteres raros que no consigo quitar.

```js
e.preventDefault();
var paqueteDeDatos = new FormData();
paqueteDeDatos.append('archivo', $('#campoFichero')[0].files[0]);
paqueteDeDatos.append('campo', $('#campo').prop('value'));
var destino = url;
$.ajax({
  url: destino,
  type: 'POST',
  data: paqueteDeDatos,
  processData: false,
  cache: false,
  success: function(resultado) {},
  error: function() {}
});
```

Comment: Tienes que pasarle el contentType en la llamada https://stackoverflow.com/a/553572

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes que meterle el content-type

```
e.preventDefault();
var paqueteDeDatos = new FormData();
paqueteDeDatos.append('archivo', $('#campoFichero') [ 
[0].files[0]);
paqueteDeDatos.append('campo', 
$('#campo').prop('value'));
var destino = url;
$.ajax({
  url: destino,
  type: 'POST',
  contetnType:"application_json; charset=utf-8",
  data: paqueteDeDatos,
  processData: false,
 cache: false,
  success: function(resultado) {},
  error: function() {}
   });
```

Comment: Ya lo he intentado pero no funciona..

Comment: As probado a declararlo en la cabecera?                                         <?php header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf8"); ?>

Comment: Estamos trabajando con ASP Clasico